# How do I update Ruby live site after editing production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I am very new to Ruby, and was wondering how I can update the live site after editing some files (for UI purposes) directly on production.

We're running Unicorn at the moment. The script is installed in the /root/ribbot/ribbot/ folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails caches source code, view templates etc: if they change then you need to restart unicorn.

Unicorn does have a seamless restart function: send a USR2 signal to the unicorn master process: this causes a new master process to be started. When this is up and running, send QUIT to the old one. GitHub have a good [blog post](https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn) on how they do this

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how you are serving your app. If you're using heroku, do `git add .`, `git commit -m "init`" (replacing init with your commit message) and `git push heroku master`.

If you're running something else, just re-deploy.